# Algorithm to optimise the cost to choose a subset of array

Tags: time-complexity, dynamic-programming

I have been on this problem for very long time, Lets assume we have a shopping list eg:`{milk,bread,coke,orange,apple,..}` and the shop only sells pack of thing and not individual things eg: `[{milk, bread}, {bread,orange} , {orange,apple} ...]`. Given the cost of each package. Is there any algorithm to minimize the cost such that we get all items from our list. I have not able to find a better algorithm than bruteforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the (weighted) [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).  It is NP-hard, so there is not likely to be any efficient algorithm that works on all problem instances.  There are various methods to deal with this: e.g., heuristic algorithms whose worst-case running time is exponential (e.g., using integer linear programming), approximation algorithms, and so on.